# Create custom shape then use UIPinchGestureRecognizer to increase and decrease size

Tags: ios, swift, shapes, pinch

I have basket court shape now I want to adjust it according to the user. User can adjust according to the direction of real environment court.

```swift
import UIKit

class basket_Court_Shape: NSObject {
    @objc dynamic public class func drawCanvas1(frame targetFrame: CGRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 240, height: 120), resizing: ResizingBehavior = .aspectFit) {
        //// General Declarations
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
        
        //// Resize to Target Frame
        context.saveGState()
        let resizedFrame: CGRect = resizing.apply(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 240, height: 120), target: targetFrame)
        context.translateBy(x: resizedFrame.minX, y: resizedFrame.minY)
        context.scaleBy(x: resizedFrame.width / 240, y: resizedFrame.height / 120)


        //// Bezier 8 Drawing
        let bezier8Path = UIBezierPath()
        UIColor.gray.setFill()
        bezier8Path.fill()
        UIColor.black.setStroke()
        bezier8Path.lineWidth = 1
        bezier8Path.stroke()


        //// Bezier 16 Drawing
        let bezier16Path = UIBezierPath()
        UIColor.black.setStroke()
        bezier16Path.lineWidth = 1
        bezier16Path.stroke()


        //// Symbol Drawing
        context.saveGState()
        context.translateBy(x: 102.5, y: 116.5)

        let symbolRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: -103, width: 63, height: 103)
        context.saveGState()
        context.clip(to: symbolRect)
        context.translateBy(x: symbolRect.minX, y: symbolRect.minY)

        basket_Court_Shape.drawCanvas2(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: symbolRect.size), resizing: .stretch)
        context.restoreGState()

        context.restoreGState()
        
        context.restoreGState()

    }

    @objc dynamic public class func drawCanvas2(frame targetFrame: CGRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 63, height: 103), resizing: ResizingBehavior = .aspectFit) {
        //// General Declarations
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
        
        //// Resize to Target Frame
        context.saveGState()
        let resizedFrame: CGRect = resizing.apply(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 63, height: 103), target: targetFrame)
        context.translateBy(x: resizedFrame.minX, y: resizedFrame.minY)
        context.scaleBy(x: resizedFrame.width / 63, y: resizedFrame.height / 103)


        //// Group
        //// Bezier Drawing
        let bezierPath = UIBezierPath()
        bezierPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 103))
        bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 103))
        bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 103))
        bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 103))
        bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 65.5))
        bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 34))
        bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1))
        UIColor.orange.setStroke()
        bezierPath.lineWidth = 2
        bezierPath.stroke()


        //// Bezier 2 Drawing
        let bezier2Path = UIBezierPath()
        bezier2Path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 23, y: 1))
        bezier2Path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1))
        bezier2Path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1))
        UIColor.orange.setStroke()
        bezier2Path.lineWidth = 2
        bezier2Path.stroke()


        //// Bezier 3 Drawing
        let bezier3Path = UIBezierPath()
        bezier3Path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 24, y: 103))
        bezier3Path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 103))
        UIColor.orange.setStroke()
        bezier3Path.lineWidth = 2
        bezier3Path.stroke()


        //// Bezier 5 Drawing
        let bezier5Path = UIBezierPath()
        bezier5Path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 62.94, y: 50.5))
        bezier5Path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 24, y: 103), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 62.94, y: 50.5), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 66.28, y: 103))
        UIColor.orange.setStroke()
        bezier5Path.lineWidth = 2
        bezier5Path.stroke()


        //// Bezier 6 Drawing
        let bezier6Path = UIBezierPath()
        UIColor.black.setStroke()
        bezier6Path.lineWidth = 2
        bezier6Path.stroke()


        //// Bezier 4 Drawing
        let bezier4Path = UIBezierPath()
        UIColor.black.setStroke()
        bezier4Path.lineWidth = 2
        bezier4Path.stroke()


        //// Bezier 7 Drawing
        let bezier7Path = UIBezierPath()
        bezier7Path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 62.98, y: 52))
        bezier7Path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 23, y: 1), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 62.98, y: 52), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 65.33, y: 1))
        UIColor.orange.setStroke()
        bezier7Path.lineWidth = 2
        bezier7Path.stroke()


        //// Bezier 9 Drawing
        let bezier9Path = UIBezierPath()
        UIColor.black.setStroke()
        bezier9Path.lineWidth = 2
        bezier9Path.stroke()


        //// Bezier 10 Drawing
        let bezier10Path = UIBezierPath()
        bezier10Path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 42, y: 23.5))
        bezier10Path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 23.5))
        bezier10Path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 82))
        bezier10Path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 42, y: 82))
        UIColor.orange.setStroke()
        bezier10Path.lineWidth = 2
        bezier10Path.stroke()


        //// Bezier 11 Drawing
        let bezier11Path = UIBezierPath()
        bezier11Path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 42, y: 23.5))
        bezier11Path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 42, y: 83.5))
        UIColor.orange.setStroke()
        bezier11Path.lineWidth = 2
        bezier11Path.stroke()


        //// Bezier 12 Drawing
        let bezier12Path = UIBezierPath()
        bezier12Path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 42, y: 35.5))
        bezier12Path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 44, y: 35.5))
        UIColor.orange.setStroke()
        bezier12Path.lineWidth = 2
        bezier12Path.stroke()


        //// Bezier 14 Drawing
        let bezier14Path = UIBezierPath()
        bezier14Path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 42, y: 71.5))
        bezier14Path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 44, y: 71.5))
        UIColor.orange.setStroke()
        bezier14Path.lineWidth = 2
        bezier14Path.stroke()


        //// Bezier 13 Drawing
        let bezier13Path = UIBezierPath()
        UIColor.orange.setStroke()
        bezier13Path.lineWidth = 2
        bezier13Path.stroke()


        //// Bezier 20 Drawing
        let bezier20Path = UIBezierPath()
        bezier20Path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 57.98, y: 52))
        bezier20Path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 44, y: 71.5), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 57.98, y: 52), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 59.14, y: 71.5))
        UIColor.orange.setStroke()
        bezier20Path.lineWidth = 2
        bezier20Path.stroke()


        //// Bezier 21 Drawing
        let bezier21Path = UIBezierPath()
        UIColor.orange.setStroke()
        bezier21Path.lineWidth = 2
        bezier21Path.stroke()


        //// Bezier 23 Drawing
        let bezier23Path = UIBezierPath()
        UIColor.orange.setStroke()
        bezier23Path.lineWidth = 2
        bezier23Path.stroke()


        //// Bezier 15 Drawing
        let bezier15Path = UIBezierPath()
        UIColor.orange.setStroke()
        bezier15Path.lineWidth = 2
        bezier15Path.stroke()


        //// Bezier 18 Drawing
        let bezier18Path = UIBezierPath()
        UIColor.orange.setStroke()
        bezier18Path.lineWidth = 2
        bezier18Path.stroke()


        //// Bezier 22 Drawing
        let bezier22Path = UIBezierPath()
        bezier22Path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 58, y: 52))
        bezier22Path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 44, y: 35.5), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 58, y: 52), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 56.83, y: 35.5))
        UIColor.orange.setStroke()
        bezier22Path.lineWidth = 2
        bezier22Path.stroke()
        
        context.restoreGState()

    }




  
    public enum ResizingBehavior: Int {
        case aspectFit /// The content is proportionally resized to fit into the target rectangle.
        case aspectFill /// The content is proportionally resized to completely fill the target rectangle.
        case stretch /// The content is stretched to match the entire target rectangle.
        case center /// The content is centered in the target rectangle, but it is NOT resized.

        public func apply(rect: CGRect, target: CGRect) -> CGRect {
            if rect == target || target == CGRect.zero {
                return rect
            }

            var scales = CGSize.zero
            scales.width = abs(target.width / rect.width)
            scales.height = abs(target.height / rect.height)

            switch self {
                case .aspectFit:
                    scales.width = min(scales.width, scales.height)
                    scales.height = scales.width
                case .aspectFill:
                    scales.width = max(scales.width, scales.height)
                    scales.height = scales.width
                case .stretch:
                    break
                case .center:
                    scales.width = 1
                    scales.height = 1
            }

            var result = rect.standardized
            result.size.width *= scales.width
            result.size.height *= scales.height
            result.origin.x = target.minX + (target.width - result.width) / 2
            result.origin.y = target.minY + (target.height - result.height) / 2
            return result
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: ok! I have basket_court shape I want the user can increase and decrease size of shape by drag on screen I think we will used Pinch Gesture Recognizer for achieved this task